# Accessing Numpy in MSYS2 shell (where MINGW64 works fine, Windows 10)?

Tags: python, numpy, msys2

I have MSYS2 on Windows 10 installed, and within it, I've installed numpy for Python3 via `pacman`:

```
$ pacman -Ss numpy | grep installed
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-numpy 1.16.2-1 [installed]
```

If I start a MINGW64 `bash` shell, then importing `numpy` is fine:

```
user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MINGW64 /c/temp
$ python3 -c 'import numpy'

user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MINGW64 /c/temp
$
```

But, when I do the same from a MSYS2 `bash` shell, first I have to explicitly add "site-packages" to `PYTHONPATH` so that `numpy` is found by Python - and even then, something goes wrong:

```
user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MSYS /c/temp
$ python3 -c 'import numpy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MSYS /c/temp
$ PYTHONPATH='/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages' python -c 'import numpy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using /usr/bin/python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Turns out, this `_multiarray_umath` is a dll:

```
$ find / -name '*multiarray_umath*'
/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath-cpython-37m.dll
```

... so I thought, maybe I should also "hack" the $PATH, but no dice:

```
user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MSYS /c/temp
$ PATH="$PATH:/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages" PYTHONPATH='/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages' python -c 'import numpy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using /usr/bin/python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Would it be possible, to somehow have a setup through environment variables, so that I can use `numpy` in Python3, also in MSYS2 `bash` shell?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out, that actually there are two different `python3`s as used in MINGW64:

```
user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MINGW64 /c/temp
$ ls -la `which python3`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user None 99328 Apr 23 10:20 /mingw64/bin/python3
```

... vs MSYS2 `bash` shells:

```
user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MSYS /c/temp
$ ls -la `which python3`                                                       
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user None 9039 Apr 25 08:50 /usr/bin/python3
```

So, the trick is not just to set up an environment variable like PYTHONPATH - but to call the right python; with that, now I get proper response under MSYS2:

```
user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MSYS /c/temp
$ /mingw64/bin/python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path); import numpy'
['', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python37.zip', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.7', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MSYS /c/temp
$
```

You might even be able to "cheat" with the path, to get this behavior without setting explicit absolute path:

```
# (this shows still the "old" msys python3)
user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MSYS /c/temp
$ PATH="/mingw64/bin:$PATH" ls -la `which python3`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user None 9039 Apr 25 08:50 /usr/bin/python3

# (like this, with subshell, it seems to work)
user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MSYS /c/temp
$ PATH="/mingw64/bin:$PATH" bash -c 'ls -la `which python3`'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user None 99328 Apr 23 10:20 /mingw64/bin/python3

# (but can seemingly call python3 without subshell)
user@DESKTOP-XYXYXY MSYS /c/temp
$ PATH="/mingw64/bin:$PATH" python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path); import numpy'
['', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python37.zip', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.7', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/bin', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', 'C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

# (program exits without a problem)
```